# Integrate exponential over shifted square root

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

Does anyone know how to compute the following integral?

$$\int^t_0 e^{-a t'}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t-t'}}dt'$$ where $a>0$.

When I plug this into wolfram alpha, I get an imaginary error function term which is both a function of $t$ and $t'$, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Not wolfram, but maple 11 on a windos 98 virtual machine:

AI := Int(exp(-a*x)/sqrt(t-x), x = 0 .. t);
-                    t
-                  /
-                 |   exp(-a x)
-        AI :=  |   ---------- dx
-                 |          1/2
-                /    (t - x)
-                0
> A := value(AI);
-               1/2     1/2    1/2
-         erf(t    (-a)   ) Pi    exp(-a t)
-    A := ---------------------------------
-                          1/2
-                      (-a)
The use of erfi is by hand for avoid the minus on a, and convert to reals all values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set $\sqrt{t-t'}=u$. Then $du=\frac{-dt'}{2\sqrt{t-t'}}$. Hence your integral is equal to 
$$
2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{t}}du\ e^{-a (t-u^2) }=2e^{-at}\int_0^\sqrt{t}du\ e^{a u^2}\ ,
$$
which can be solved in terms of the [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function).

Answer (score 1):

It gives to me $${\frac {\sqrt {\pi}{{\rm e}^{-a\,t}}{\it erfi} \left( \sqrt {a\,t}  \right) }{\sqrt {a}}}$$ where ${\it erfi} \left( x \right) =2\,{\frac {\int_{0}^{x}\!{{\rm e}^{{t}^{2}}}\,{\rm d}t}{ \sqrt{\pi}}}$

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the exact expression you used in wolfram?